# C# to Json serializing object within object throwing bad request

Tags: c#, json

I have a simple object that i have defined

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class survey
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string deploymentType { get; set; }
    public string deploymentMethod { get; set; }
    public string instanceId { get; set; }
    public surveyWhat what { get; set; }
    public string[] contacts { get; set; }
}

public class surveyWhat
{
    public bool removeDuplicates { get; set; }
    public string instanceId { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string bcc { get; set; }
    public string emailTemplate { get; set; }
    public string notificationId { get; set; }
}
```

when building an actual object with these 2 classes, I do so as follows.

```
survey s = new survey()
        {
            title = "test from .Net",
            description = "test of immediate email deployment",
            deploymentType = "immediate - deploy",
            deploymentMethod = "email",
            instanceId = "bla123",
            what = new surveyWhat()
            {
                removeDuplicates = false,
                subject = "test from .Net",
                from = "a@b.c",
                bcc = "a@b.c",
                emailTemplate = "123id",
                notificationId = "a@b.c"
            },
            contacts = new string[] { "user@person.com" }
        };
```

I then take this object and using NewtonSoft.Json dll, I serialize the object into a JSON String to pass to a REST endpoint like so.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {                
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

This throws a 400 bad request error. The JSON appears valid, but fails on me. Can it have something to do with the object within an object causing this?

```
object() { object(){} }
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I am using .Net 4.5.2 for this build.

Comment: A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules. We don't know anything about your API, what are it's expectations. You say JSON appears to be valid. Server responded it's not, so I rather think you have to take a look at it one more time. Maybe read some docs of your API.

Comment: Thanks walkerbox. I will re-look at it again. Appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it's good enough for answer to your question, so as I said in comment:

> A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data
>   stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules. We
>   don't know anything about your API, what are it's expectations. You
>   say JSON appears to be valid. Server responded it's not, so I rather
>   think you have to take a look at it one more time. Maybe read some
>   docs of your API.

And now more -  You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) application to test requests to your API. If you do not have docs, this way you could find what is the proper request. Then, when you know what are the proper request data, you could check json string generated by serialization, and check what is wrong.